# SVG not working in Firefox (and works in Opera/Chrome/IE 9)

Tags: firefox, background, svg

What's wrong with SVG image?
(it is not working in Firefox)

```
data:image/svg+xml;base64,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  +PC9kZWZzPjxyZWN0IHg9IjAiIHk9IjAiIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIGZpbGw9InVybCgjYSkiLz48L3N2Zz4=
```

Comment: what version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: Can you describe what features the image is using?  There are some features that dont seem to be supported.

Comment: Firefox 5, SVG, i use linearGradient (rect with width=100% height 100%) here and nothing else

Comment: Seems, problem with dataURL... svg from file works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that older Firefox versions don't support fragment identifiers for data: URLs.  This is fixed in Firefox 6.  See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=308590